# Do standalone applications not need an application server to run?

Tags: java, application-server, oracle-coherence

I am working on a standalone (non web) multi-threading trading application. It is started every night at 11 pm using a start script. We do not use an application server to deploy this application. We use oracle-coherence for HA and scalability. I do not understand is how does it work without an application server? I thought an application server is needed if we want to perform transactions, support multi-threading, etc.

Comment: What you need to run java code is a called a Java Runtime Environment (JRE). There are multiple implementations of that. Among other things, this includes/implements a Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Comment: *"I thought an application server is needed if we want to perform transactions, support multi-threading"* it's not. Threads are part of the Standard Edition, transactions (if you're talking about database transactions) are supported by JDBC

Comment: An application server is an application specialized for serving multiple (web)applications and conveniently handling/filtering requests to them. You don't *need*  an application server - you can also provide a WebApplication as a standalone application, but then you need to implement all the communication infrastructure yourself (or use a library that provides it).

Comment: I have news for you - an "application server" is just an application. :) 

If it's open source (e.g., Tomcat), take a look at the code, at some point, you'll find a `public static void main(...)` in there.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I wonder when an application server is needed?

Answer (score 2):

You don't require application or web server for non-web application. Your application is running on JVM installed on local machine. Multithreading and DB transactions(through JDBC) are supported by JVM so you don't need application server.

Comment: Thanks Saurabha. I wonder why and when to use an application server?

Comment: If you want to build application on client- server model(similar to stackoverflow.com, gmail, Facebook, gmail etc.), where user would be accessing your application through browser or any other client apps, then you would require to build a web application(may use J2EE or other web app development technologies) and deploy application on any server(servlet container enabled web servers or applications servers).